# Management/Leadership/Social Type Careers in Statistics?

Tags: careers

I'm a graduate student in statistics and have been working on a number of projects recently, some of which I've taken a bit of a leadership role in. I am starting to have a hunch that I might enjoy a more people-oriented career than a software (or similar kind of skill) type career. I certainly enjoy some forms of coding, but I think what I like most is working directly with others, teaching, discussing ideas, making research plans, analyzing figures (rather than making them), writing introductions and discussions (rather then methods and results sections), etc. And in general I am a very social, somewhat extroverted person.

My question is: what are the managerial (or other leadership-type) niches in industry or government for statisticians? Or more generally, what kind of niches are there if I am happiest working with people?

Does anybody have tips for how to get into such a type of career? Would a PhD (which I want to do anyways) be helpful or hindering over a Masters in this regard?

Cheers!